# Installing mpi4py and vcvarsall issue

Tags: python, compiler-construction, mpi

Trying to install `mpi4py` and having an issue when I run

```
easy_install mpi4py
```

and get:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

From reading literature on similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880231/problem-with-mpich2-mpi4py-installation) I figured it is a compiler issue, but I have no idea how to implement the fix mentioned in that problem. From `mpi4py` [documentation](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html) I found

`env MPICC=/path/to/mpicc easy_install mpi4py`

I am on Windows and cmd doesn't allow me to run such command. I'm not too familiar with Windows command line, so dont know how to properly implement this fix, or is this even a correct fix?

`easy_install mpi4py MPICC=/path/to/mpicc` isnt an option as `easy_install` doesnt have an argument for passing down variables.

I am using OpenMPI

**EDIT 1**

vcvarsall.bat file is in my VS12 folder, so most likely it is the same issue as the outlined in above case. I am using Developer Command Prompt from VS12, and no luck either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had luck getting python compiles to work on windows. Luckily I've never had a compelling need for it either. Can you try [the unofficial binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py) installer?

If you need to install it to a virtualenv, first activate your virtualenv and then use `easy_install "..."` with the full path to the downloaded binary.

If you really need to compile it, you'll need to follow what all the other solutions say about getting compilation to work on windows.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been looking for something like this all day!